# jQuery validation - element is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using a jquery.validation plugin to validate my inputs on the form

I use it as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
jQuery(function () {
    // You can specify some validation options here but not rules and messages

    jQuery('form[id="reservationForm"]').validate({ ignore: ":not(:visible)" });

    $("#adult1Birthdate").mask("9999-99-99");
    $("#reservationPersonBirthdate").mask("9999-99-99");

    $("#adult1Firstname").rules("add", { required: true, minlength: 2, messages: { required: '<span style="color:Red">Pole wymagane</span>'} });
});
```

});

I get the following error however:

> element is undefined

in the following line:

```
var settings = $.data(element.form, 'validator').settings;
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
**EDIT**
```

Also the following code does not work when I use jquery.validation

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
$(function () {

                $('a[id^="regionDetails"]').click(function () {
                    var vid_id = $(this).attr("id").replace("regionDetails", "#regionDetailsArea");
                    $('div[id^="regionDetailsArea"]').hide();
                    $(vid_id).show();
                    return false;
                });
            });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `$`, don't use `jQuery`. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#reservationForm:visible').validate();

  $("#adult1Birthdate").mask("9999-99-99");
  $("#reservationPersonBirthdate").mask("9999-99-99");

  $("#adult1Firstname").rules("add", { required: true, minlength: 2, messages: { required: '<span style="color:Red">Pole wymagane</span>'} });

  $('a:not(#regionDetails)').click(function() {
    $('div:not(#regionDetailsArea)').hide();
    $($(this).attr("id").replace("regionDetails", "#regionDetailsArea")).show();

    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: ok, I removed $(document).ready(...) and now it works, however Firebug gives me another error: $("#adult1Birthdate").mask is not a function . I am using jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js

Comment: Post your `<head>` tag contents. You're probably loading the plugin too early. Also, *don't* remove `$(document).ready(`!!!

Comment: well, the error disappers but now my form is not validated after I removed $(document).ready. The strange is that when I got this $(document).ready, my other jquery method doesn't work;/

Comment: You need `$(document).ready()` because your code will run before the webpage is fully ready to be tinkered with and may lead to horribly inconsistent results.

Comment: I know, and this seems to be an issue. I have this code inside a separate javascript file. When I have $(document).ready() something strange happens because my css is also broken. My page looks very odd. When I add $(document).ready() my other jquery method is not working

Comment: Post your other jQuery method.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the element you're calling `.rules()` on does exist, `jquery.validate` doesn't check for it when adding rules and fails miserably at the described line, simply because the element is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that when this error appears for me, I have an input being called in rules that I don't have defined in my form. Or, vice versa.